# How to change default document root to sudo user document root in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: sudo, root

I am new to Ubuntu. By following some tutorials I was able to set up a NodeJs and express server as root user. And everything worked as expected, I was able to bring my .ejs file in browser.

After that, going through some security tips online I realized that its better to use a sudo user and disable root login.

So I set up a fresh server with sudo user. So now my NodeJs server is located at `home/user1` (when looked from root). But whenever I go to browser it displays default homepage located at `/var/www/html`.

How can I make my files being accessed from sudo user location? Help would be appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "sudo user location"? `/var/www/html` looks like a perfectly normal location where web pages for a server live. Clarify what you precisely want.

Comment: @vanadium, I only see default home page even if I run command `npm start` to start server (which starts alright). So I presume home page is coming from superuser controlled files not from server which is setup under sudo user.